# How to implement the collapse/Expand section to the right using html /css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I implement the expanding the section to the right when I click on Even more info
In the below code sample when I click on Even More Info it is showing down of the Even More Info. How to do the right exactly opposite to the `EvenMoreInfo` section

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
  margin: 1.2rem 0;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #DDD;
  background: #0069ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(0, 105, 255, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 105, 255, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.collapsible-content p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-collabsible"> <input id="collapsible2" class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked=""> <label for="collapsible2" class="lbl-toggle">Even More Info</label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p> Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly capicola ground round brisket. Shank pork belly cupim fatback. Flank porchetta chicken spare ribs. Ham prosciutto pork belly turkey beef picanha strip steak swine alcatra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can any one please help me on it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `max-height`'s to `max-width`'s and the `position` of the `.collapsible-content` and it will work, like so:

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
  margin: 1.2rem 0;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #DDD;
  background: #0069ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width .25s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 240px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 240px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(0, 105, 255, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 105, 255, .45);
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.collapsible-content p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-collabsible"> <input id="collapsible2" class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked=""> <label for="collapsible2" class="lbl-toggle">Even More Info</label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p> Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly capicola ground round brisket. Shank pork belly cupim fatback. Flank porchetta chicken spare ribs. Ham prosciutto pork belly turkey beef picanha strip steak swine alcatra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But are you sure, this is what you wanted? First, I saw this image in your first posting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNvBX.png